# Extract careers,employee url with based on Mechanize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize

Extract careers, employee url with based on Mechanize and help me to get  inside careers page under I have to extract at least one link of careers_urls under careers page

`ex:
  agent = Mechanzie.new

  carrier_page = agent.get("http://www.mitel.com/mitel-careers").click`

after that I don't know do finding list of careers page links

Thank's for advance....

Comment: What you exactly want to do?? @siva subramanian

Comment: i would like to collect under all websites  careers url  i did that. but., eg:(http://www.mitchellsandham.com/Careers.aspx,http://www.mitchellsd.org/mitchellsd/job-opportunities,.....) under this one url list of jobs will there that what i want to collect  if you know just help me... @NarasimhaReddy

Comment: confirm me whether you want job links in this page http://fpmgs.avature.net/mitelcareers

Comment: yes but it should dynamic using this Mechanzie @NarasimhaReddy

Answer (score 0):

Try this. it gives all urls of job openings in the page which i have passed into `get` method.

```
    agent = Mechanize.new
    page = agent.get('http://fpmgs.avature.net/mitelcareers')
    page.css('.jobResultItem').css('a').map { |k| k.attributes['href'].value }
```

pass link with pagination value to get other links . example 
http://fpmgs.avature.net/mitelcareers/SearchJobs/?jobOffset=20
 pass
above link, it gives next urls in the page.

Comment: i am having 50000 url of carrier page (that what i am saying dynamically).... and thanks  for your valuable information. @NarasimhaReddy